# Define Stack and Queue as Abstract Data Types

Tags: types, stack, queue, abstract-data-type

I'm currently trying to define abstract data types in a "precise" way, but I'm struggling with it currently. The entire point of the exercise is to define them without specifying any implementation detail. I'm using `stack` and `queue` here, as they are simple examples, but the problem can be generalised. My attempt so far has been based on constraints:

A stack is the type of objects with constructor `Stack()` and methods `push(o)` and `pop()`, so that for any `List originalList` (in pseudocode):

```
stack = Stack()
for o in originalList:
    stack.push(o)
while obj = stack.pop() != NIL:
    newList.append(obj)
assert(newList == originalList.reverse())
```

For a queue, it would be the same, but the final line would be `assert(newList == originalList)`.

My problem is that this "definition" requires "actual computation" and "assertion", in contrast to e.g. statically saying that a `LinkedList` is a pair `(value, next)`, so that next is a pointer to an element of the same type.

Is there a better way to go about this? Can anyone point me to suitable literature?